# How are const char and char pointers represented in memory in STM32

Tags: c, pointers, stm32

How does MCU now that the string a variable is pointing on is in data memory or in program memory?
What does compiler do when I'm casting a `const char *` to `char *` (e.g. when calling `strlen` function)?
Can `char *` be used as a `char *` and `const char *` without any performance loss?

Comment: Sidenote: `strlen` already expects `const char *str`. You can pass both const and non-const versions without casting.

Comment: Also, your question is too broad. Constness can affect where variable is placed (RAM vs ROM) by the compiler/linker, but that all is dependent on your tools *and* the processor architecture. According to tag wiki STM32 covers various ARM Cortex cores, and you haven't even specified the compiler you are using.

Comment: On a system where the flash is just address mapped like any other memory, there is no difference in the generated machine code between `char*` and `const char*`. If you use `char* const` though, then there's a significant difference, namely that the compiler will try to allocate the pointer itself in NVM, rather than RAM.

Comment: You should never use unnecessary casts. You can always assign a `char *` to a `const char *`, just not the other way (and you should not enforce this by a cast).

Comment: @Lundin: The same can apply for the objects `const char *` points to if the compiler can deduce them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking a STM32F4 example with 1MB flash/ROM memory and 192KB RAM memory (128KB SDRAM + 64KB CCM) - the memory map looks something as follows:

- Flash/ROM - 0x08000000 to 0x080FFFFF (1MB)
- RAM - 0x20000000 to 0x2001FFFF (128KB)

There's more areas with separate address spaces that I won't cover here for the simplicity of the explanation. Such memories include Backup SRAM and CCM RAM, just to name two. In addition, each area may be further divided sections, such as RAM being divided to bss, stack and heap.

Now onto your question about strings and their locations - constant strings, such as:

```
const char *str = "This is a string in ROM";
```

are placed in flash memory. During compilation, the compiler places a temporary symbol that references such string. Later during linking phase, the linker (which knows about concrete values for each memory section) lays down all of your data (program, constant data etc.) in each section one after another and - once it knows concrete values of each such object - replaces those symbols placed by the compiler with concrete values which then appear in your binary. Because of this, later on during runtime when the assignment above is done, your `str` variable is simply assigned a constant value deduced by the linker (such as 0x08001234) which points directly to the first byte of the string.

When it comes to dynamically allocated values - whenever you call malloc or new a similar task is done. Assuming sufficient memory is available, you are given the address to the requested chunk of memory in RAM and those calculations are during runtime.

As for the question regarding `const` qualifier - there is not meaning to it once the code is executed. For example, during runtime the `strlen` function will simply go over memory byte-by-byte starting at the passed location and ending once binary `0` is encountered. It doesn't matter what "type" of bytes are being analyzed, because this information is lost once your code is converted to byte code. Regarding `const` in your context - `const` qualifier appearing in function parameter denotes that such function will not modify the contents of the string. If it attempted to, a compilation error would be raised, unless it implicitly performs a cast to a non-const type. You may, of course, pass a non-const variable as a const parameter of a function. The other way however - that is passing a const parameter to a non-const function - will raise an error, as this function may potentially modify the contents of the memory you point to, which you implicitly specified to be non-modifiable by making it `const`.

So to summarize and answer your question: you can do casts as much as you want and this will not be reflected at runtime. It's simply an instruction to the compiler to treat given variable differently than the original during its type checks. By doing an implicit cast, you should however be aware that such cast may potentially be unsafe.

Comment: Ok. So basing on same example, does STM32F4 have same instruction for load from SRAM and load from FLASH?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there are no separate instructions, because the area you want to load or store data from or to is already indicated by the address you pass. It may then be decided "in hardware" when the instruction and its arguments are decoded which memory should be "talked to". For more informations about available memory access instructions I suggest checking this: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Chdhbfcd.html

Answer (score 2):

The STM32s use a flat 32-bit address space, so RAM and program memory (flash) are in the same logical space.

The Cortex core of course knows which type of memory is where, probably through hardware address decoders that are triggered by the address being accessed. This is of course way outside the scope of what C cares about, though.

Dropping `const` is not a run-time operation, so there should be no performance overhead. Of course dropping `const` is *bad*, since somewhere you risk someone actually believing that a `const` pointer means data there won't be written to, and going back on that promise can make badness happen.

Answer (score 0):

With and without const, assuming your string is truly read only, is going to change whether it lands in .data or .rodata or some other read only section (.text, etc).  Basically is it going to be in flash or in ram.

The flash on these parts if I remember right at best has an extra wait state or is basically half the speed of ram...at best. (Fairly common for mcus in general, there are exceptions though).   If you are running in the slower range of clocks, of you boost the clock the the ram performance vs flash will improve.  So having it in flash (const) vs sram is going to be slower for any code that parses through that string.

This assumes your linker script and bootstrap are such that .data is actually copied to ram on boot...